# Is the function $f(x) = tan(x)$ odd, even, or neither?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Is the function $f(x) = \tan(x)$ odd, even, or neither?

**Here is what I have so far:**

I know the function is not even because $f(x) ≠ f(-x):$

$$f(-x) = \tan(-x)$$

$$\tan(-x) ≠ \tan(x)$$

Now I want to determine if the function is odd. I know a function is odd if $f(x) = -f(-x)$:

$$-f(-x) = -\tan(-x)$$

How does the negative sign on the outside of the brackets affect $\tan(-x)?$

My instinct is that **the function is neither even nor odd,** but I would like confirmation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the definition of $\tan$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and use the fact that $\sin$ is odd, and $\cos$ is even :

$$\tan(-x)=\dfrac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)}=\dfrac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\tan(x).$$

Comment: If sin is odd and cos is even, would that make tan odd?

Comment: @McB Yes, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

another way to show that is $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\ tan(x) dx =0 ,\  a>0$$ where $f(x)$ is an even  function , this fact has a nice geometric explanation, odd function is symmetric about x-axis, so the area between $x=0$ and $x=a$ above is same as the area between $x=0$ and $x=-2$  but in  opposite direction.

P.S: $\ f(x)=1$ is sufficient